# Has method to crop camera output changed in AndoKitkat

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.4-kitkat

I used to capture and crop at the same time using below code. Now it stops working in Kitkat. Do I need to do it in other way?

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempUri);
cameraIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
cameraIntent.putExtra("outputX", defaultWidth);
cameraIntent.putExtra("outputY", defaultHeight);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
```

Or do I need to start a separate intent for crop?

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", defaultWidth);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", defaultHeight);
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
```